# How to perform different behaviors based on the length of variadic args in cpp macro?

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-macros, fmt

I'm trying to make a short-hand for logging (log4cplus) + libfmt. I have defined a macro in my util header:

```
#define T_TRACE(fs, ...) \
    LOG4CPLUS_TRACE(Logger::Instance().logger, fmt::format(fs, __VA_ARGS__).c_str())
```

Then, every other cpp just include this header, invoke `T_TRACE` to perform logging. e.g.
`T_TRACE("Version is {}", "1.0.0");`
Everything works fine until I want to log a string contains `{}` pair (a simple json string).
`T_TRACE("{\"name\": \"value\"}")`, the `fmt` lib will treat it as a formatter, so I need to inform the macro that insert a default placeholder `"{}"` for me if there is only one argument.

The reason for using macro is that I also want to log the source file and lines. If I wrap it in a function, all the file/line info would be in that wrapper function.

Comment: What is the real problem this macro is intended to solve? No, not the one related to the number of arguments to the macro, but the real problem to which the solution is believed to be a macro that does something like this. Perhaps once the real problem is described, a more appropriate solution will become evident.

Comment: ya, i also didnt get what the problem was. @LQsLLDB Can you explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: Try to avoid using macros. There are *very few* real reasons to use macros in modern C++ - variadic templates, `constexpr`, `consteval` or just plain old runtime code/functions can handle most situations.

Comment: ... In fact, having reread this, `FORMAT()` is just a trivial overload of two functions, one regular function, and one that uses variadic templates. I would expect every modern C++ compiler to inline the end result, which is: no fugly macros, just plain, clean C++. And IIRC, gcc can be pragma-ed to force it to always inline the end result. C'mon. just say "no" to macros.

Comment: [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location)

Comment: @RaymondChen Any c++17 and below solution?

Comment: Sure, use a macro to add source and line to the call to `FORMAT()`, which gets implemented as two overloaded functions: `FORMAT()` with one (additional) parameter, and a variadic template `FORMAT()`. Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I come up with a solution based on Kramer's answer.
Unamed logging:
`T_TRACE(config) => FMT_SERIALIZER_RESULT`

```
#define T_TRACE(o, ...) \
    LOG4CPLUS_TRACE(Logger::Instance().logger, LogImpl(o, __VA_ARGS__).c_str())

template <typename T, typename... args_t>
inline auto LogImpl(const T& obj, args_t&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args_t))
        return fmt::format(obj, args...);
    else
        return fmt::format("{}", obj);
}
```

Named logging:
`T_TRACE(config) => config: FMT_SERIALIZER_RESULT`

```
#define T_TRACE(o, ...) \
    LOG4CPLUS_TRACE(Logger::Instance().logger, LogImpl(#o, o, __VA_ARGS__).c_str())

template <typename T, typename... args_t>
inline auto LogImpl(const char* name, const T& obj, args_t&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args_t))
        return fmt::format(obj, args...);
    else
        return fmt::format("{}: {}", name, obj);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).

```cpp
#define T_TRACE(...) \
    LOG4CPLUS_TRACE(Logger::Instance().logger, fmt::format( \
        BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_GREATER(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), 1), \
        BOOST_PP_EMPTY, "{}" BOOST_PP_COMMA)() __VA_ARGS__).c_str())
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/z9Ts44xz7). Note that `fs` is not taken as a separate parameter, since before C++20 empty variadic macro arguments are very tricky to process portably.

It would be a lot simpler if you were using C++20 or later, since that has `__VA_OPT__` and thus BOOST_PREPROCESSOR_VA_OPT:

```cpp
#define T_TRACE(fs, ...) \
    LOG4CPLUS_TRACE(Logger::Instance().logger, fmt::format( \
        BOOST_PP_VA_OPT((fs,), ("{}", fs), __VA_ARGS__) __VA_ARGS__).c_str())
```

However, since C++20 you can just use `std::source_location`, which makes this macro (though not some other macros) unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

The real solution is to NOT using macros at all (you should use them only if there is no other option anyway). In most cases you can use variadic function templates. Also note that if you provide a runtime format string you need to use fmt::vformat and fmt::make_format_args.

```
template<typename... args_t>
void T_TRACE(std::string_view format_string, args_t&&...args)
{
    auto output = fmt::vformat(format_string, fmt::make_format_args<args_t>(args));
    LOG4CPLUS_TRACE(Logger::Instance().logger, output.c_str());
}
```

If you would still need to change behavior based on the number of arguments (which I doubt) you can use `sizeof...(args_t)` and `if constexpr(sizeof...(args_t)) == some_constant_value)`

Comment: It worked, but lost the file/line info

Comment: You can call T_TRACE with `__FILE__, __LINE__`  arguments on the place of logging